# excel formula reference to existing column entries

Tags: excel

This is presumable a simple one. What's the difference between:

```
$F$3
```

and:

```
F3
```

when used in an Excel formula. IMHO there is no difference.

Comment: Google relative and absolute cell reference: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference for any one cell, but the point of absolute/relative references(dollar signs, or lack thereof) is that when writing a formula in one cell, but then wanting a similar formula to appear in several nearby cells, you can 'drag/copy' the formula across cells or down cells.

Then the formula will also apply to those cells. the dollar signs means the reference to F3 will be absolutely fixed across all the formulas. Lack of dollar signs means that the columns and rows will increment as the formula is dragged/copied.

`=SQRT(F3)`

So if you dragged such a formula above from A1 across and down to C3, there would be 9 different formulas in those cells. The last one in C3 would say:

`=SQRT(H5)`

This could be useful for filling a column or row. If you applied dollar signs such as `=SQRT($F$3)`, then the last formula in C3 would still say `=SQRT($F$3)`